# Вывод страницы с уведомлением после отправки сообщения

Tags: php, файлы

Есть рабочий код-обработчик обратной связи:

```
<? 

// если не было добавления сообщения, выводим форму
if (!$_POST['a']) show_form();

// проверяем данные формы
if (!$_POST['name']) show_form("Укажите Ваше имя!");
if (!$_POST['email']) show_form("Укажите Ваш email!");
if (!$_POST['message']) show_form("Вы не заполнили текст сообщения!");

// описываем переменные и rfc заголовки письма

// обратный адрес будет указанным адресом отправителя сообщения
$from = $_POST['email']; 
$recipients = "besidetrue@besidetrue.ru"; // Ваш email
$subject="";
$body=$_POST['message'];
$headers = $_POST['subject']; 

if(strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], '(Win32)')===FALSE)
{
    // открываем sendmail и отправляем письмо
    $mail = popen("/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -f$from -- $recipients", 'w');
    $text_headers = "from: $from\nsubject: $subject".$headers;
    fputs($mail, $text_headers);
    fputs($mail, "\n");
    fputs($mail, $body);

    // проверяем на ошибку
    $result = pclose($mail) >> 8 & 0xff;
}
else $result=(mail($recipients, $subject, $body, "from: ".$from."\r\n".$headers) ? FALSE : TRUE); 
if ($result) echo "Сообщение не было отправлено!";
else echo "Ваше сообщение отправлено.Администратор свяжется с Вами в ближайшее время!";
?>
```

Все приходит куда нужно но после отправки сообщения выдает "Ваше сообщение отправлено и тд " на БЕЛОМ ФОНЕ совершенно игнорируя измененный дизайн под сайт.Это и есть проблема.

Что делать?

Нужно чтобы после отправки выводилась страница сайта с этим уведомлением в центре. php знаю лишь поверхностно и очень нужна помощь.

Comment: моя логика такая(если без аякса):
сделайте один блок(див) с ИД "мессаге", в цсс дисплей=ноне(скрытая);
и при появлений пост запросов засунте сообщения соответственно к ПОСТ-у.
пример:

    if($_POST['email_result']=='OK')
    {msg = "Successfull!";} else {msg = "";}
    
    template.php
    
    <div id="message">{msg}</div>

Answer (score 3):

Если я не ошибаюсь,

```
echo "Ваше сообщение отправлено.Администратор свяжется с Вами в ближайшее время!"
```

выдаёт просто текст, не html-страницу. (Браузеры умеют отображать просто текст тоже.) Вы же должны выдать html с нужными стилями. Посмотрите, как генерируются другие страницы, и делайте так же. Возможно, есть общая процедура, которой вы передаёте контент, а она генерирует html с нужной шапкой и стилями, воспользуйтесь ею. Может быть, вам нужно просто воспользоваться `show_form` вместо `echo`?

Кроме того, в вашем коде огромная дыра в безопасности, сквозь которую пролезет не только квалифицированный хакер, но и школьник вроде меня. Вы не проверяете данные, пришедшие от клиента, и используете их как часть команды. Можно легко подделать, например, `$_POST['email']`, чтобы оно равнялось `"abcd@efgh.ru; rm -rf /; echo"`. Прикиньте, что станет с сервером?

Comment: за оба пункта ++++ =) Хотя с сервером ничего не будет, если конечно сервер не под рутом был запущен... а вот сайт легко легко удалится)

Comment: @thunder: Спасибо!

Comment: Доброго времени!
Спасибо всем за ответы.Для меня важна практически любая информация по теме и около.
По правде говоря,этот "код" просто подарок для спамботов ит пт.Ни капчи ни инфоскана.Это я понимаю:)
фрисофт со всеми вытекающими...Но он единственный рабочий из 20 тестированных. 
НЕзнающего пхп "обидить" может каждый.Грустно, но я учусь.
Буду искать дальше.
Может кто знает,где взять более-менее надежную и рабочую связь?